# Why is the principal branch of $\ln(z)$ different from $z^{1/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

From what I understand the principal of $\ln(z)$ is defined as:
$$ \ln(z)=Ln(r)+i\theta$$
where $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi]$ but the principal brance of $z^{1/2}$ is defined as:
$$z^{1/2}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$$
where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. From what I can see their is noting wrong with using $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ for both functions (or indeed $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi]$). Is it just convention that they are defined differently or is there a reason behind it?

Comment: The usual convention for the square root is also $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi].$ When you use the word "principal", it is for the argument taking value in $(-\pi,\pi].$